# window.postMessage(...) for a cross domain file upload?

Tags: ajax, html, cross-domain

Does someone know if it's possible to make a cross domain file upload with window.postMessage(...) or, alternatively, of another technique to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe about time you select an answer here? Both provider are relevant, and one points to a complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to combine a regular `POST` for sending the data with `postMessage` (or equivalent for legacy support) for the response.

You can see how this is done with easyXDM [here](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/07/22/uploading-files-cross-domain-ajax-style/)

Answer (score 0):

window.postMessage() can only send strings back and forth, so you can't send binary data.  You could just do a standard form post to a different domain.